# javascript for loop incrementing momentjs date by 1 day,

Tags: javascript, momentjs

```
const datePeriod = ("2020-05-13") => {
  const date = moment(dateFrom);
  var dates = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++) {

    dates.push({ date: date.add(i, "days").format("YYYY-MM-DD") });

  }
  console.log(dates);
};
```

i want get result like below

[
    {
        "date": "2020-05-13"
    },
    {
        "date": "2020-05-15"
    },
    {
        "date": "2020-05-16"
    },
    {
        "date": "2020-05-17"
    },
    {
        "date": "2020-05-28"
     ...... }]

but i am actully getting like below, why is it ? it suppose to increment by 1 right ?

[
    {
        "date": "2020-05-13"
    },
    {
        "date": "2020-05-14"
    },
    {
        "date": "2020-05-16"
    },
    {
        "date": "2020-05-19"
    },
    {
        "date": "2020-05-23"
...... }]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`date.add` will mutate the initial date. If you *want* to mutate the initial date, you can just add `1` each time:

```js
dates.push({ date: date.add(1, "days").format("YYYY-MM-DD") });
```

Your other option is to clone the date on each loop to make sure you're not mutating the original date:

```js
const copiedDate = moment(date);
dates.push({ date: copiedDate.add(i, "days").format("YYYY-MM-DD") });
```

Answer (score 1):

That’s because at every iteration `i` is incremented by 1, and you’re **modifying the date in place**, so the increment becomes additive, i.e. you +1 day in the first iteration, and then in the next iteration you use the new date and +2 more days to it, so on and so forth.

A possible fix is either always add 1 day in the loop instead of `i`:

```
dates.push({ date: date.add(1, "days").format("YYYY-MM-DD") });
```

Or you can create a new moment object in each iteration but that’s a little more expensive. In other words, you move the `const` declaration into the loop:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    const date = moment(dateFrom);
    dates.push({ date: date.add(i, "days").format("YYYY-MM-DD") });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should move dateFrom inside for loop instead of global one.

```
 for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    const date = moment(dateFrom);
    dates.push({ date: date.add(i, "days").format("YYYY-MM-DD") });
  }
```

```js
const datePeriod = (dateFrom) => {
  
  var dates = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    const date = moment(dateFrom);
    dates.push({ date: date.add(i, "days").format("YYYY-MM-DD") });
  }
  console.log(dates);
};

 datePeriod("2020-05-13");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.1/moment.min.js" integrity="sha256-zG8v+NWiZxmjNi+CvUYnZwKtHzFtdO8cAKUIdB8+U9I=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```